# How to add 2 hour to time string with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I have two datetime-local input star time is for user changeable and the other one is read-only and I want to update that field by jquery.

```
<input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="deliveryTime" id="DeliveryTime" required>
```

```
<input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="deliveryTimeEnd" id="DeliveryTimeEnd" readonly>
```

```
$("#DeliveryTime").on("change", function() {
           var startTime = $("#DeliveryTime").val();
            startTime.setHours(startTime.getHours()+2);
            alert(startTime);
            $("#DeliveryTimeEnd").val(startTime);
            
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first chnage the startTime in datetime format like below code and then get the hours

```
var dt = new Date(startTime);
dt.setHours(dt.getHours() + 2);
```

Complete code is:

```
 $("#DeliveryTime").on("change", function() {
    var startTime = $("#DeliveryTime").val();
    alert(startTime);
    var dt = new Date(startTime);
    dt.setHours(dt.getHours() + 2);
    alert(dt.toLocaleString("sv-SE"));
    $("#DeliveryTimeEnd").val(dt.toLocaleString("sv-SE"))
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was not quite as trivial as I assumed in the beginning. Here is a snippet that sets the second datetime input to a time 2 hours after the time of the first input:

```js
abc.time1.addEventListener("input",ev=>{
 const dt=new Date(abc.time1.value);
 dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes()-dt.getTimezoneOffset()+120);
 abc.time2.value=dt.toISOString().slice(0,-5);
});
```

```html
<form name="abc">
<input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="time1"><br>
<input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="time2">
</form>
```